# Inserting data into Database CodeIgniter 3.x

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to insert data into a MySqli table using CodeIgniter 3.x.

For some reason none of the database methods defined in the CodeIgniter Query Builder [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data) seem to be working for me.

Using

```
$data = array(
'created_at' => date('Y/m/d h:i:s'),
'updated_at' => date('Y/m/d h:i:s'),
'first_name' => $firstName,
'last_name' => $lastName,
'email' => $email,
'auth_key' => $password,
'enabled' => '1',
'deleted' => '0');

$test = $this->db->insert('users', $data);
```

Gives me the error: Call to undefined method 'insert'. This is the method defined in the CodeIgniter Documentation. I am calling this code from my Controller, although I have also tried it in my Model.

I have been able to successfully run SQL statements and get data from the Database using the code here:

```
    $query = $this->db->table('users')
             ->select('*')
             ->where($this->table . '.auth_key', $password)
             ->where($this->table . '.email', $email)
             ->where($this->table . '.enabled', 1)
             ->get()->getRowArray();
```

However, this differs from the syntax I see in the documentation. How would one go about inserting the $data array into the users table in a MySQLi DB??

Thanks, and let me know if I need to clarify anything!

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. Are you certain you have loaded the database and that you are properly connected to it?

Comment: I have loaded the database and properly connected to it, the second half of my code runs fine and returns valid results from the database. When I go to insert data into my table with the code in the first snippet I get an error saying that insert is a "Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Connection::insert() ".

Comment: i'm pretty sure you are using some kind of 3rd party tool instead of the querybuilder because there is no `table()` function in it - so your query `$this->db->table()..` wouldn't even work with Codeigniter 3.x - i assume u use CI 4..., which is a total different thing because it isn't even out of alpha state.(currently still in dev in phase 2)

Comment: @Pecans dear you are mixing CI 3 and CI 4, the link you given above is for CI 3, here is for CI 4 : https://bcit-ci.github.io/CodeIgniter4/database/index.html

Comment: you should use $db      = \Config\Database::connect();
$builder = $db->table('users'); $builder->insert($data); to insert the record like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to finally work using:

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (created_at, updated_at, first_name, last_name, email, auth_key, enabled, deleted) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %d, %d)", $data['created_at'], $data['updated_at'], $data['first_name'], $data['last_name'], $data['email'], $data['auth_key'], $data['enabled'], $data['deleted']);

$this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: @least correct your question - because according of what you've shown so far you r using CI 4

Answer (score 1):

Use Insert_String instead of Insert may be it's solve your problem,

```
$data = array(
'created_at' => date('Y/m/d h:i:s'),
'updated_at' => date('Y/m/d h:i:s'),
'first_name' => $firstName,
'last_name' => $lastName,
'email' => $email,
'auth_key' => $password,
'enabled' => '1',
'deleted' => '0');

$test = $this->db->insert_string('users', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are passing wrong date format, MySQL date format should be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, update your code like following

```
$data = array(
    'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'first_name' => $firstName,
    'last_name' => $lastName,
    'email' => $email,
    'auth_key' => $password,
    'enabled' => '1',
    'deleted' => '0'
);
$this->db->insert('users', $data);
return ($this->db->trans_status()) ? $this->db->insert_id() : false;
```

make sure you are loading database `$this->load->database();` in `__construct` & you `created_at` & `updated_at` mysql column should be `DATETIME`